# Implementation of Analog Matched Filter

Tags: analog, filter, signal, communication, signal-processing

I have been reading about communication theory and I was wondering if matched filters can be implemented with analog parts and what they would look like?

If they can't be it seems like the matched filter construct is of only theoretical interest without any practical implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analog matched filters are widely used in special cases where they have been in practice possible to construct. Examples:

- dispersive delay line in chirp pulse compression radar; an acoustic surface wave filter
- integrator to detect rectanqular DC pulses (actually a pulse lenght delay line and a subtractor are also needed if we haven't a clock which keep the integrator reset when no pulses are expected to arrive)

For arbitary complex pulses analog matched filters are impractical because the needed tolerances are not manageable.

NOT ASKED, but maybe useful: Detection with correlator is mathematically equivalent with using a matched filter. For example  greenbacks were in first gasoline automates recognized this way in analog domain. A candidate slided over a half transparent greenback image. If there occurred a sudden peak in the total light penetration, the candidate at least had right greenback patterns.

ADD due a comment:

The questioner asked a link to an existing implementation. Unfortunately I have no such weblink. But I can include one version which should be plausible altough hopelessly impractical when compared the equivalent processing in digital domain.

Here's a matched filter for 1 second long rectangular DC pulses. The impulse response of such filter should be also one second long rectangular DC pulse.

That impulse response is possible to generate with an integrator. The length 1s is achieved by subtracting the same input delayed by 1 second. Subtraction and integration are possible to realize with a differential amplifier and integrator which are made of opamps. In the next image they are built both with one opamp:

[image]

If the integration time constant is 1s (for ex. R=100kOhm, C=10uF), one volt DC pulse would generate 1 volt high triangle pulse to the output.

To prevent integrator to drift to saturation there are discharging resistors Rd, drawn with dashed line. Having R=100kOhm, I would try Rd = 500kOhm...1MOhm. Discharging time constant 5...10s should not spoil the filtering of 1s pulses and surely wins at least  the drift caused by non-idealities of modern high performance opamps.

1 second linear delay is problematic. If one accepts quite low system bandwidth - say 5kHz - a looped tape recorder can be used. It unfortunately doesn't record DC, but the signal can be shifted upper with mixing:

[image]

When the signal has been stored 1s, it's taken out and mixed back to 0Hz. The written mixing method is AM, which is inefficient due the generated lower sideband + carrier. But it's simple technically and the needed carrier frequency (more than 10kHz, say 12kHz) + both sidebands are still well recordable and possible to get separated (=filtered) from the leaked input signal at the output of the modulator.

The lowpass filter at the input of the whole system kills those signals which are out of the 5kHz bandwidth.

Comment: So the next two questions would be - what exactly do you measure at the output of the matched filter? If you send a signal through a matched filter and integrate you maximize the L^2 norm but what does this mean in terms of circuits? You can't implement a continuous integrator because it would accumulate the sums of all prior signals.

Comment: @FourierFlux Sorry, a wrong comment occurred. Deleted. Retry: There's a level detector at the output of the matched filter. The voltage jumps when a pulse is totally arrived to the filter. Integrator is a part of the filter, if it's useful due the pulse shape. DC pulses need it . The general impulse response rule (=pulse reversed in time) gives it. The level detector decides if there's enough peak voltage over the noise.

Comment: Hmm, ok so you can do some type of peak detector with a certain threshold which triggers when the output voltage is high enough - this doesn't take into account the entire time interval though? How do you deal with the accumulation of noise in the integrator? Something needs to initially trigger it as I don't think there is a way to do a sliding continuous integrator without it going into saturation.

Comment: @FourierFlux The integrator - if it's needed in the filter - can forget gradually with a little harm when the discharging time constant is long compared to the length of the matched pulse.

Comment: Interesting, this makes sense. I guess the key is to make sure filter is good enough to prevent signals outside of the bandwidth from contributing at a rate faster then the integrator discharges. Once detection occurs the cap will need to be fully discharged and the process restarts. Have a link to implementation?

Comment: @FourierFlux I added an imaginary implementation example. I have not any weblinks to the schematics of really built implementations. The signal (=1s DC pulses) is not widely used detectable in noisy environments, but its matched filter is simple.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, will a delay always need to be added for a matched filter?

Comment: @FourierFlux Not as dicrete element, but very likely as ability to store the pulse to be able to form the output  based on the whole pulse.

Answer (score 2):

The spectral density ( amplitude spectrum) of the signal would match the amplitude filter response.

The phase response would depend on how critical this is to the integrity of the signal and its derivative, group delay near band edge.

This general approach is used for heart signals (EKG) with HP,LP shaping filters and digital spectrum as well for all kinds.  This optimizes the SNR as long as phase requirements are given such as zero ISI (intersymbol interference).  The tradeoffs depend on SNR input and desired SNR output.

Comment: How does phase response of a filter relate to its impulse response? I couldn't find any information on this.

Comment: convolution in the time domain corresponds to multiplication in the frequency domain, and any linear filter frequency response has both an amplitude and phase characteristic, which is the DFT of the impulse response.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a matched filter's impulse (time-domain) response is a time-reversed replica of the signal being matched. This is easy to do in the digital domain, and this is where the technique is most useful.

it is very difficult to accomplish using analog components alone for arbitrary signals. However, if you design the filter first, you can then design the signal that matches it. This could be a useful thing to do in some applications.

Answer (score 1):

Examine this patent, by Peter Halpern (assisted by Peter Mallory, who brought the methods of maximum-likelihood to the trigonometric-matched-filter synthesis)
regarding Halpern's paper of 1972.

http://www.google.com/patents/US4403331